# Zedboard Linux Socket Application Error

Tags: fpga, xilinx, linux

After creating the linux boot image from the tutorial for the zedboard, I tried creating a socket application to talk to the computer. The Zedboard would be the server and the program in visual studio would be the client. When I try to run the program from the linux command prompt, it pops up with "error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". When I ran a hello world program from the sd card on the Zedboard, it did not give me this error and worked just fine. Could this be a cause of the includes I am using? Both the client and server were written in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the includes but the linker command line. If you have a dependency to libstdc++.so, then probably there is a -lstdc++ there.

First, you need to check if that library is really necessary, so remove that option from the link command. If you're still able to link the program, the problem is solved. If not, then you really need it and have to put it back.

In that case, you need to find out if there is some version of that .so in your system. In general, your program depends on the non-versioned name (libstdc++.so), and in your /lib or /usr/lib directory there are symbolic links that point to the actual version the system has (in your case apparently libstdc++.so.6). This may be another symbolic link to a more specific version (e.g. libstdc++.so.6.1) or the actual dynamic library. So you have to follow that trail and discover where it's broken, if the library does exist.

And if it does not, you have to install it somehow (usually with the package manager of your OS)

Comment: Thanks! I checked for that libstdc++ file and I did not find any version of it, however, I did find a version of libstdc. So I moved my code into a C file instead of C++ and it worked.

Comment: OK, that probably means that your system has support libraries for C but not C++. That's not unusual for constrained embedded systems, since C++ libs are more heavyweight. If you can use just plain C in these cases, it's better.